# SQL populate total working days per month minus bank holidays for current financial year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, reporting-services

I am after a view which will look like my first attached picture however with right hand column populated and not blank. The logic is as follows:

The data must be for **current** financial period. Therfore April will be 2011 and March will be 2012 and so on.

The calculation for Days Available for the single months will be:

Total number of working days (Monday-Friday) minus any bank holidays that fall into that particular month, for that particular financial year (Which we have saved in a table - see second image).

Column names for holiday table left to right: **holidaytypeid**, **name**, **holstart**, **holend**.
Table name: **holidaytable**

To work out the cumulative months **'Days Available'** it will be a case of summing already populated data for the single months. E.g April-May will be April and May's data SUMMED and so on and so forth.

I need the SQL query in perfect format so that this can be pasted straight in and will work (i.e with the correct column names and table names)

Thanks for looking.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `dates` table, a table that has a list of every date? If not, then I'd recommend you get one.

Comment: No I dont have such a table and am unable to create tables on this db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME

SELECT  @StartDate = '01/04/2011',
        @EndDate = '31/03/2012'
        
CREATE TABLE #Data (FirstDay DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, WorkingDays INT NOT NULL)

;WITH DaysCTE ([Date]) AS
(   SELECT  @StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
    FROM    DaysCTE
    WHERE   [Date] <= @Enddate
)

INSERT INTO #Data
SELECT  MIN([Date]),
        COUNT(*) [Day]
FROM    DaysCTE
        LEFT JOIN HolidayTable
            ON [Date] BETWEEN HolStart AND HolEnd
WHERE   HolidayTypeID IS NULL
AND     DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Date]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)

DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SET @Date = (SELECT MIN(FirstDay) FROM #Data)

SELECT  Period,
        WorkingDays [Days Available (Minus the Holidays)]
FROM    (   SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, Firstday) [Period],
                    WorkingDays,
                    0 [SortField],
                    FirstDay
            FROM    #Data
            UNION
            SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, @Date) + ' - ' + DATENAME(MONTH, Firstday),
                    (   SELECT  SUM(WorkingDays)
                        FROM    #Data b
                        WHERE   b.FirstDay <= a.FirstDay
                    ) [WorkingDays],
                    1 [SortField],
                    FirstDay 
            FROM    #Data a
            WHERE   FirstDay > @Date
        ) data
ORDER BY SortField, FirstDay

DROP TABLE #Data
```

If you do this for more than 1 year you will need to change the line:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366)
```

Otherwise you'll get an error - The number needs to be higher than the number of days you are querying.

---

**EDIT**

I have just come accross this old answer of mine and really don't like it, there are so many things that I now consider bad practise, so am going to correct all the issues:

1. [I did not terminate statements with a semi colon properly](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
2. Used a recursive CTE to generate a list of dates

   - [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
   - [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
   - [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
3. [Did not include the column list for an insert](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
4. Used DATENAME to elimiate weekends, which is language specific, much better to explicitly set `DATEFIRST` and use `DATEPART`
5. Used `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` instead of `NOT EXISTS` to elimiate records from the holiday table. [In SQL Server LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is less efficient than NOT EXISTS](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

These are all minor things, but they are things I would critique (at least in my head if not outloud) when reviewing someone else's query, so can't really not correct my own work! Rewriting the query would give.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20110401',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '20120331';

CREATE TABLE #Data (FirstDay DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, WorkingDays INT NOT NULL);

WITH DaysCTE ([Date]) AS
(   SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
            DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @StartDate)
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
)
INSERT INTO #Data (FirstDay, WorkingDays)
SELECT  FirstDay =  MIN([Date]),
        WorkingDays = COUNT(*) 
FROM    DaysCTE d
WHERE   DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Date]) NOT IN (6, 7)
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    dbo.HolidayTable ht
            WHERE   d.[Date] BETWEEN ht.HolStart AND ht.HolEnd
        )
GROUP BY DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]);

DECLARE @Date DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(FirstDay) FROM #Data);

SELECT  Period,
        [Days Available (Minus the Holidays)] = WorkingDays 
FROM    (   SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, Firstday) [Period],
                    WorkingDays,
                    0 [SortField],
                    FirstDay
            FROM    #Data
            UNION
            SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, @Date) + ' - ' + DATENAME(MONTH, Firstday),
                    (   SELECT  SUM(WorkingDays)
                        FROM    #Data b
                        WHERE   b.FirstDay <= a.FirstDay
                    ) [WorkingDays],
                    1 [SortField],
                    FirstDay 
            FROM    #Data a
            WHERE   FirstDay > @Date
        ) data
ORDER BY SortField, FirstDay;

DROP TABLE #Data;
```

As a final point, this query becomes much simpler with a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql) that stores all dates, and has flags for working days, holidays etc, rather than using a holiday table that just stores holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add few cents to this post. Just got assignment to calculate difference between planned hours and actual hour. The code below was converted to a function. So far no issue with the logic:

```
declare @date datetime = '11/07/2012'
declare @t table (HolidayID int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
    HolidayYear int,
    HolidayName varchar(50),
    HolidayDate datetime)

INSERT @t
VALUES(2012, 'New Years Day', '01/02/2012'),
(2012,'Martin Luther King Day', '01/16/2012'),
(2012,'Presidents Day', '02/20/2012'),
(2012,'Memorial Day', '05/28/2012'),
(2012,'Independence Day', '07/04/2012'),
(2012,'Labor Day', '09/03/2012'),
(2012,'Thanksgiving Day', '11/22/2012'),
(2012,'Day After Thanksgiving', '11/23/2012'),
(2012,'Christmas Eve', '12/24/2012'),
(2012,'Christmas Day', '12/25/2012'),
(2013, 'New Years Day', '01/01/2013'),
(2013,'Martin Luther King Day', '01/21/2013'),
(2013,'Presidents Day', '02/18/2013'),
(2013,'Good Friday', '03/29/2013'),
(2013,'Memorial Day', '05/27/2013'),
(2013,'Independence Day', '07/04/2013'),
(2013,'Day After Independence Day', '07/05/2013'),
(2013,'Labor Day', '09/02/2013'),
(2013,'Thanksgiving Day', '11/28/2013'),
(2013,'Day After Thanksgiving', '11/29/2013'),
(2013,'Christmas Eve', NULL),
(2013,'Christmas Day', '12/25/2013')


DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME, 
    @END_DATE DATETIME, 
    @Days int

SELECT  @START_DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0) 

SELECT  @END_DATE = DATEADD(month, 1,@START_DATE)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, number, (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @date), 0) )) CDate
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values where type = 'p' and number between 0 and 365
        EXCEPT
    SELECT HolidayDate FROM @t WHERE HolidayYear = YEAR(@START_DATE) 
)
SELECT @Days = COUNT(CDate) --, datepart(dw, CDate) WDay
FROM CTE 
WHERE (CDate >=@START_DATE and CDate < @END_DATE) AND DATEPART(dw, CDate) NOT IN(1,7)

SELECT @Days
```