# SQL Server adding a record record manually to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a view which contains the data seen in the image below.
The view is showing me how many working days are available in each month for the current financial year taking away any school/bank holidays.

As the month of August has zero days available it has excluded this month from the view.

As the total number of days available will always be zero for the month of August, then it seems acceptable to hardcode the SQL to always have 0 for August, and also an April-August record which will be the same as April-July.

What would be the best way to add these 2 records, and where about in the code should it be placed see example of code layout:

see link (answered question) for layout of code:

> [SQL populate total working days per month minus bank holidays for current financial year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180274/sql-populate-total-working-days-per-month-minus-bank-holidays-for-current-financ)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I will assume you have a view `vDays` with columns that match your screen shot: `period`, `availabledays`,  `year`.

To append any zero-day periods to your results whatever month may have zero (which will cater for August and any other month that happens to have zero days), you can extend your view like this:

```
WITH Mths (Mth) AS (
    SELECT 'January'
    UNION SELECT 'February'
    UNION SELECT 'March'
    UNION SELECT 'April'
    UNION SELECT 'May'
    UNION SELECT 'June'
    UNION SELECT 'July'
    UNION SELECT 'August'
    UNION SELECT 'September'
    UNION SELECT 'October'
    UNION SELECT 'November'
    UNION SELECT 'December'
    UNION SELECT 'April - January'
    UNION SELECT 'April - February'
    UNION SELECT 'April - March'
    UNION SELECT 'April - May'
    UNION SELECT 'April - June'
    UNION SELECT 'April - July'
    UNION SELECT 'April - August'
    UNION SELECT 'April - September'
    UNION SELECT 'April - October'
    UNION SELECT 'April - November'
    UNION SELECT 'April - December'

), Years (Year) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT year
    FROM   vDays

), ZeroPeriods (Mth, Years) AS (
    SELECT Mth, Year
    FROM   Mths, Years

), JoinedData (Mth, AvailableDays, Year) AS (
    SELECT Mth, 0, Years
    FROM   ZeroPeriods
    UNION ALL
    SELECT period, availabledays, year
    FROM   vDays

), GroupedData (Mth, AvailableDays, Year) AS (
    SELECT Mth, SUM(AvailableDays), Year
    FROM JoinedData
    GROUP BY Mth, Year

)
SELECT * 
FROM   GroupedData
ORDER BY Year, CASE UPPER(LEFT(Mth, 3)) 
               WHEN 'JAN' THEN 1 WHEN 'FEB' THEN 2 WHEN 'MAR' THEN 3
               WHEN 'APR' THEN 4 WHEN 'MAY' THEN 5 WHEN 'JUN' THEN 6
               WHEN 'JUL' THEN 7 WHEN 'AUG' THEN 8 WHEN 'SEP' THEN 9
               WHEN 'OCT' THEN 10 WHEN 'NOV' THEN 11 ELSE 12 END;
```

I have split this out into lots of separate queries, although some could be merged into sub queries, but doing it like this makes it a lot clearer to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Would this give you your desired result set?

```
SELECT Period, DaysAvailable, Year FROM YOURVIEW
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'April-August', DaysAvailable,  Year FROM YOURVIEW where Period = 'April-July'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'August', 0, YEAR FROM YOURVIEW
```